# SharePoint 2019 - Top Bat Navigation link

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, 2019, windows-server-2016

I am absolutely beginner to the SharePoint. Today I have installed SharePoint 2019 on Windows Server 2019. Created the first root site. Created an Alternative access mapping to site. And that's it. If I remember correctly I didn't made any changes.

There are a couple of issues right now.

**Issue 1:**

Image - 1

[image: Blue Color Logo]

As in Image-1 when I click on the big SharePoint Logo it is taking me to the Home Page. That is fine.

Image -2

[image: Link is referring to the local source]

When I click on the SharePoint text which is next to the 9 dots it is taking me to the local source as you can see in the image-2 http://sp/my/_layouts

How we can fix it. Please guide me through the process.

**Issue 2:**

When I am logging with locally like http://sp it is asking for credentials only once. When I am trying to login with the domain it is asking for credentials several times like 3 - 16 times and this is happening each time I am refreshing the page or moving on to the somewhere else in the site. Basically, if a page refresh / load is happening it is asking me for credentials multiple times. 
I need help resolving this issue.

The resolution for these will persist for each subsite I create if yes then is there any way I can apply solution globally.

**Update**

EDIT:

I can confirm that issue-1 has been resolved. Adding site details to the alternative access mapping has fixed the issue.

About issue-2 even after applying loop-back-check or BackConnectionHostNames or applying both didn't fixed the issue.

Let's say page has 10 images and several js files. For these each resource I am getting login prompts.

If I am using NTLM then for each login prompt part of page resources is loading.

What I have found is if am changing authentication method from NTLM to basic then those multiple prompts is gone. Asking for one time login prompt and not asking for anymore until I logout.

Many thanks for your time.

ACE

Answer (score 1):

Issue 1 isn't an issue. That is by design. It is taking you to SharePoint Home which shows your followed sites, news, etc. Last I looked, there was no setting to change this behavior.

For Issue 2, if you're browsing from the Windows Server running SharePoint, you need to disable loopback check or use back connection hostnames. See [KB926642](https://support.microsoft.com/help/926642/error-message-when-you-try-to-access-a-server-locally-by-using-its-fqd) for instructions.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I did something in alternate Access mapping in administration section and url is directing as per the website. I am still looking into how did i fixed it. As for the second issue lets I am accessing it from my mobile or from linux or Windows 7 workstation. I will look into the article you posted.

Answer (score 1):

1. As Trevor mentioned, this is by design. It's impossible to change it. SharePoint Home is a new feature in SharePoint 2019.You could refer to this article for more:
   https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/sites/enable-sharepoint-home-page-in-sharepoint-server-2019-farms
2. It's a known issue. You could try this workaround for loop back check issue in SharePoint:https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/workaround-for-loop-back-check-issue-in-sharepoint/

Comment: Yes, I have tried those methods but it didn't solved my issue. I have updated my post on what causing this. I will keep looking into NTLM authentication method on why it is causing me multiple login prompts.